# Making a div fixed once scrolled past

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made a jQuery function which is supposed to make three elements fixed beneath the nav bar once scrolled past. I have got it kinda working but theres kinda a glitch. The function is constantly flicking between fixed and static as I scroll. What have I done wrong?

```js
function scroll_past() {
   var jobs_cont = jQuery("#jobs_cont").outerHeight() / 2;
   var top_position = jQuery("#jobs_cont").offset().top;
   var position = jobs_cont + top_position;

   var nav_height = jQuery("#top_fluid_cont").height();
   var wind_pos = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + nav_height;

   if (wind_pos >= position) {
      jQuery(
         "#jobs_cont, .job_info, .job_title, .salary, .cv_button, .jobs_br, .jobs_space"
      ).addClass("fixed");
   } else {
      jQuery(
         "#jobs_cont, .job_info, .job_title, .salary, .cv_button, .jobs_br, .jobs_space"
      ).removeClass("fixed");
   }
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
   scroll_past();
});
```

```css
body{
   height: 5000px;
}

#top_fluid_cont{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

#nav{
   background-color: grey; 
}

#image{
 background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507090960745-b32f65d3113a?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=2700&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   height: 100vh;
}

#jobs_cont.fixed{
    margin-top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
}

.job_info.fixed{
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.job_title.fixed{
 font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.salary.fixed{
 font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.cv_button.fixed{
 display: none;
}

.jobs_br.fixed{
 display: none;
}

.jobs_space.fixed{
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="top_fluid_cont">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="nav">
         <h1>Navigation</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="image">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" id="jobs_cont">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
         <div class="jobs">
            <h2 class="job_title">Construction Site<br class="jobs_br"><span class="jobs_space"> </span>Supervisor role</h2>
            <p class="salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
            <p class="job_info">Our client is a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add an experienced Construction Site Supervisor to their team. <a href="#">See More</a></p>
            <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-4">
         <div class="jobs">
            <h2 class="job_title">Construction Contracts<br class="jobs_br"><span class="jobs_space"> </span>Manager role</h2>
            <p class="salary">Salary: £40,000 – £45,000</p>
            <p class="job_info">Our client is a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add an experienced Construction Contracts Manager to their...<a href="#">See More</a></p>
            <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
         <div class="jobs">
            <h2 class="job_title">Graduate Quantity<br class="jobs_br"><span class="jobs_space"> </span>Surveyor role</h2>
            <p class="salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
            <p class="job_info">Our client a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add a Graduate Quantity Surveyor to their team. <a href="#">See More</a></p>
            <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/WZBrba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the glitch is the fact that by applying the class `fixed` to `#job_cont` you're moving `#job_cont` up, which causes the code to trigger again and remove the class.

A possible solution to this would be to add an element, which doesn't move, but has the same position as `#job_cont`. This is what I did in the provided code snippet.

Check 
`<div id="scrollCheck"></div>` in the snippet.

```js
function scroll_past() {
   var jobs_cont = jQuery("#scrollCheck").outerHeight() / 2;
   var top_position = jQuery("#scrollCheck").offset().top;
   var position = jobs_cont + top_position;

   var nav_height = jQuery("#top_fluid_cont").height();
   var wind_pos = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + nav_height;

   if (wind_pos >= position) {
      jQuery(
         "#jobs_cont, .job_info, .job_title, .salary, .cv_button, .jobs_br, .jobs_space"
      ).addClass("fixed");
   } else {
      jQuery(
         "#jobs_cont, .job_info, .job_title, .salary, .cv_button, .jobs_br, .jobs_space"
      ).removeClass("fixed");
   }
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
   scroll_past();
});
```

```css
body{
   height: 5000px;
}

#top_fluid_cont{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

#nav{
   background-color: grey; 
}

#image{
 background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507090960745-b32f65d3113a?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=2700&h=&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   height: 100vh;
}

#jobs_cont.fixed{
    margin-top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
}

.job_info.fixed{
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.job_title.fixed{
 font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.salary.fixed{
 font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.cv_button.fixed{
 display: none;
}

.jobs_br.fixed{
 display: none;
}

.jobs_space.fixed{
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="top_fluid_cont">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="nav">
         <h1>Navigation</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="image">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" id="jobs_cont">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
         <div class="jobs">
            <h2 class="job_title">Construction Site<br class="jobs_br"><span class="jobs_space"> </span>Supervisor role</h2>
            <p class="salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
            <p class="job_info">Our client is a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add an experienced Construction Site Supervisor to their team. <a href="#">See More</a></p>
            <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-4">
         <div class="jobs">
            <h2 class="job_title">Construction Contracts<br class="jobs_br"><span class="jobs_space"> </span>Manager role</h2>
            <p class="salary">Salary: £40,000 – £45,000</p>
            <p class="job_info">Our client is a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add an experienced Construction Contracts Manager to their...<a href="#">See More</a></p>
            <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
         <div class="jobs">
            <h2 class="job_title">Graduate Quantity<br class="jobs_br"><span class="jobs_space"> </span>Surveyor role</h2>
            <p class="salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
            <p class="job_info">Our client a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add a Graduate Quantity Surveyor to their team. <a href="#">See More</a></p>
            <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
         <div id="scrollCheck"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I will accept this answer as it works. Although I decided to just rearrange my code to achieve the same result. But that wouldn't of been possible if you hadn't pointed out the problem

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this, you can simply use [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning).

Comment: position: sticky has very limited browser support (sadly!).
http://caniuse.com/css-sticky/embed/